# How would you improve the efficiency of this regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing, java.util.scanner

I think my regex pattern I have used could be tidied up and look a little neater but my knowledge of regular expressions is limited. I would like to scan and match a series of letters and numbers on new lines from an input file.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.regex.*;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    if (args.length == 1) {

        String fileName = args[0];
        String fileContent = new Scanner(new File(fileName))
                .useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

        ArrayList<Integer> parsedContent = new ArrayList<>();
        parsedContent = parseContentFromFileContent(fileContent);

        int firstInt = parsedContent.get(0);
        int secondInt = parsedContent.get(1);
        int thirdInt = parsedContent.get(2);
        int fourthInt = parsedContent.get(3);
        int fifthInt = parsedContent.get(4);

        System.out.println("First: " + firstInt);
        System.out.println("Second: " + secondInt);
        System.out.println("Third: " + thirdInt);
        System.out.println("Fourth: " + fourthInt);
        System.out.println("Fifth: " + fifthInt);

        return;
    }
  }

  public static ArrayList<Integer> parseContentFromFileContent(String fileContent) {

    ArrayList<Integer> parsedInts = new ArrayList<>();

    String pattern = "(.+?).((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)?\\n..((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)?\\n(.+?).((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern, Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(fileContent);

    if (m.matches()) {
        // Group 1: Has to match two letters
        switch (m.group(1)) {
            case "ab":
                parsedInts.add(1);
                break;
            case "cd":
                parsedInts.add(2);
                break;
            case "ef":
                parsedInts.add(3);
                break;
        }

        // Group 2: Has to match a number
        parsedInts.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));

        // Group 3: Has to match a letter
        parsedInts.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));

        // Group 4: Has to match a single letter
        switch (m.group(4)) {
            case "a":
                parsedInts.add(1);
                break;
            case "b":
                parsedInts.add(2);
                break;
            case "c":
                parsedInts.add(3);
                break;
        }
        // Group 5: Has to match a number
        parsedInts.add(Integer.parseInt(m.group(5)));
    }
    return parsedInts;
  }

}
```

Input file:

```
ab-123 // Group 1 - Two letters a-z and Group 2 - Number
A=1    // Group 3 - Always A= [number]
a-1    // Group 4 - Letter a-z and Group 5 - Number

cd-1234
A=2
b-2

ef-12345
a=4
c-3

gh-123456
a=4
d-4
```

Is there a better (cleaner) regex pattern I could use to capture the data from the file above.

```
pattern = (.+?).((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)?\\n..((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)?\\n(.+?).((?:\\d*\\.)?\\d+)
```

Comment: In your pattern you use a lot of `.+?` where your descriptions says `two letters` or `always A=` - you could be as specific as your description, so use `[a-z]{2}` or `A=`. Also your regex accounts for decimal numbers, while there are none in the shown input, so you might be able to drop `(?:\\d*\\.)?`. Furthermore all your number matching patterns are optional, why?

Comment: So if your input always looks the way shown here, you might be as specific as [`([a-z]{2})-(\d+)\n[Aa]=(\d+)\n([a-z])-(\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/WNxUQa/1), as always double backslashes for use in java.

Comment: That's great. Thanks @SebastianProske

Comment: I don't have the ability to mark this answer as correct

Comment: because it isn't an answer, just a comment asking for clarifications. As it seems all my assumptions were correct, I will write an answer in a few moments, just going for dinner first :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern at the moment isn't very precise, contrary to the description you gave. There are a lot of `.+?`, but your description quite clearly says `two letters` or `always A=` - so you could instead use that in your pattern. Your pattern also accounts for decimal numbers, while there are none in the shown input, so you might be able to drop `(?:\\d*\\.)?`. Furthermore all your number matching patterns are optional, but according to your description thex shouldn't.

If one takes your pattern quite literally, a possible pattern would be

```
([a-z]{2})-(\\d+)\\n[Aa]=(\\d+)\\n([a-z])-(\\d+)
```

See https://regex101.com/r/WNxUQa/1

Note that you might have to adjust your pattern a bit (e.g. using `^` and `$`), if there might be malicious input.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no such thing as optimizing a regular expression, unless it contains backtracking and you can remove it. You can optimise the way it *looks*, but all regular expressions that do the same thing compile to the same DFA, or equivalent DFAs, and have the same performance.

Comment: false.  they compile either to dfa or to nfa and they do not have the same performance.  For example, if you search a regexp in a text editor the text editor may compile the regexp to NFA and apply dinamically the transitive closure to search nondeterministically  OR it can apply the transitive closure on NFA and get a non-optimized DFA and apply a deterministic search.  If you do not optimize the DFA/NFA in both cases it is slower as the number of edges/epsilong edges is bigger.

Comment: It is sure that if the compiler compiles to NFA and apply dynamically the t.c. it is slower if non-optimized.  If it compiles to DFA it is hard to say if they have or not the same performance.